# Problems Deploying a rails app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, error-handling, heroku, stack-trace

I am having problems deploying a Rails app to Heroku, I can't even run the Heroku console! (see below for the response I get from terminal)

I'm pretty new to rails and programming in general, so I don't really understand what the problem is here, would really appreciate some assistance!

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require':  /app/config/environments/production.rb:3: unknown regexp options - lcal (SyntaxError)
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:11:in `block in <module:Bootstrap>'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
  from /app/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
  from script/rails:6:in `require'
  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Here is config/environments./production.rb, I commented out line 3 as I thought that might be the issue, but I get the same problem whether it's commented, uncommented or deleted completely!

```
Pingpong::Application.configure do

# /opt/local/bin/convert


# Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

# The production environment is meant for finished, "live" apps.
# Code is not reloaded between requests
config.cache_classes = true

# Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

# Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"

# For nginx:
# config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'

# If you have no front-end server that supports something like X-Sendfile,
# just comment this out and Rails will serve the files

# See everything in the log (default is :info)
# config.log_level = :debug

# Use a different logger for distributed setups
# config.logger = SyslogLogger.new

# Use a different cache store in production
# config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

# Disable Rails's static asset server
# In production, Apache or nginx will already do this
config.serve_static_assets = false

# Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and javascripts from an asset server
# config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

# Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
# config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

# Enable threaded mode
# config.threadsafe!

# Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
# the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
config.i18n.fallbacks = true

# Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
end
```

/app/config/environment

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)



# Initialize the rails application
Pingpong::Application.initialize!
```

Comment: can you post config/environments/production.rb?

Comment: Line 3 is what's going to be causing your original problem if it's uncommented, as that's a regex in Ruby. If it's commented, you won't be getting that error. So what is the *new* error?

Comment: Hi Ryan, it doesn't matter if it's commented, uncommented or deleted, I still get the same problem! In the stack trace it also mentions line 7 in /app/config/environment, I will add that code to the question also!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is line 3. Make sure you have committed your changes and then push them to Heroku.